# Woocommerce Order Delivery plugin change display location

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a Woocommerce site that is using the following plugin: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-order-delivery/ ("WooCommerce Order Delivery")

The plugin is now displayed on the Checkout page under the billing fields in the checkout_shipping section, I am trying to change this location to the checkout_order_review section by hooking in to the functions.

But I can't seem to get it working.

My code in my functions.php:

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_shipping( $instance ) {
global $woocommerce;

  if ( is_checkout() && $woocommerce->cart->needs_shipping() ) {
     echo 'Hi World!';
    if ( wc_od() ){
     echo 'Found wc_od function';
    }

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping', 'checkout_content' );
  }
};

// add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_shipping' );
```

My thought behind this code was that I remove the function 'checkout_content' which retrieves the plugin template and then add the action to the `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` function to display it in the order review section.

But my remove_action doesn't seem to work.

The code in the plugin that adds the checkout_content action:

```
protected function __construct() {
        // WP Hooks.
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );

        // WooCommerce hooks.
        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping', array( $this, 'checkout_content' ), 99 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', array( $this, 'validate_delivery_date' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', array( $this, 'update_order_meta' ) );

        // Delivery date validation hooks.
        add_filter( 'wc_od_validate_delivery_date', array( $this, 'validate_delivery_day' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'wc_od_validate_delivery_date', array( $this, 'validate_minimum_days' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'wc_od_validate_delivery_date', array( $this, 'validate_maximum_days' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'wc_od_validate_delivery_date', array( $this, 'validate_no_events' ), 10, 2 );
    }
```

Can someone maybe give me a push in the right direction? 
Am I doing this wrong ? or is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues.

Firstly you need to specify the execution priority when you remove action, or at least you do when it is anything other than the default, 10. In your case the execution priority is 99.

Secondly, `checkout_content()` is a class function, not a standalone function so you need to specify this in the function reference.

So your `remove_action` line of code will be:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping', array( $the_class_variable, 'checkout_content' ), 99 );
```

where `$the_class_variable` is the instance of the class containing that `__construct()` function. How you refer to this depends on how the class has been instantiated in the plugin.

You can read about different ways of instantiating a class and the corresponding `remove_action` at http://jespervanengelen.com/different-ways-of-instantiating-wordpress-plugins/

You can read about `remove_action` this in https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: Thanks allot i'm going to dive into this !  Gave you a +1, gonna set your answer to solved if i manage to fix my issue.

Comment: Thanks allot !! the first url really helped me, i managed to solve my issue :)

Comment: I have the same issue but it doesn't work for me : remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping', array( $the_class_variable, 'checkout_content' ), 99 );
I'm adding this line into my child theme functions.php file

Comment: @Ravi - `$the_class_variable` is just a placeholder. You need to find out how to refer to the class in the code. Also, the WooCommerce code is constantly updated so after over 3 years, the action name and/or priority may be different now.

Comment: Hello @JamesJones, Thank you for the answer. But please let me inform you I have recently downloaded this plugin and See the same class with the same ACTION which is mentioned above.
Can you please help me how to use this variable $the_class_variable?